# Adding Models dynamically to fit the polygons size Cesium JS

Tags: polygon, cesium, 3d-model

I am trying to add 3D glb models to fit the parcel/geom size of the polygon. What i wish to do is that the model should sit within the boundary of the polygon and fit to the polygon size.

I have a shapefile which i have converted into mysql table which includes the polygon geom and the centroid points of that polygon. I want to add one model to all the polygons for the time being. Right now i can show the model on the polygon using centroid and i even tried the northeast rectangle method but i am not achieving the desired results as the polygons are of various shapes and sizes. see picture below
[image: As you can see the models are not quite centered which i guess can be rectified using buffer and then taking centroid]

Now this is my code to add the model.

```
var passedArray =  <?php echo json_encode($cords); ?>; 
for(var i = 0; i < passedArray.length; i++){ 

 var heading = Cesium.Math.toRadians(100.0);

 //pitch describes the up and down dive of the model
 var pitch = Cesium.Math.toRadians(0.0);

 //roll describes the rotation of the model on its own axis
 var roll = Cesium.Math.toRadians(0.0);

 //position describes the long,lat and the height of the model from the ground
 //xcenter and ycenter are the coordinates point taken from the table which were calculated via arcmap mysql centroid was giving a false centroid.
 var position = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(passedArray[i]['xcenter'], 
 passedArray[i]['ycenter'], 0.0);

//orientation combines all the aspects above to get the right direction and location of 3d object
var orientation = Cesium.Transforms.headingPitchRollQuaternion(position, new 
Cesium.HeadingPitchRoll(heading, pitch, roll));

//first
//adding the 3d model to the map.
//scale: the scale of the object 1.0 defines the original scale.
//glb files are mostly suited for the 3d models
 entity[i] = viewer.entities.add({
 position : position,
 orientation : orientation,
 model : {
    uri : '<?php echo base_url();?>Cesium/Apps/SampleData/models/newmodel/Bambo_House.glb',
    scale : 50.0
 }
 });

 }
```

Anyway to get the models to fit and scale perfectly within the polygon size and take the polygon boundary as its bounding box.
Regards